# Is there a way to form a "one who [verb]s" noun?

Tags: verb, noun

In English, I can take just about any verb (for example *to crush*), and form a noun which means "one who [*does that verb*]" by adding *-er* (for example, *crusher*).

Is there a similar formulaic alteration (or set of possible alterations) in German?  For example, can I take the verb *zerschlagen*, and easily change it into a noun meaning "someone who crushes"?

It seems to me that if there is a way to do this in German, there must be a more complicated rule, or more than one depending on the verb.  For instance, *paint* and *painter* translate to *malen* and *Maler*/*Malerin*, but according to Google Translate *sing* and *singer* translate to *singen* and *Sänger*.

I am not even sure what to call this *-er* verb-to-noun construction in English.  All my attempts to search on the topic of changing nouns to verbs just bring up information on gerunds, which is definitely not applicable here.  (The gerund form of a verb would mean "the act of [*doing the verb*]", which is definitely not what I am looking for.)

Comment: Skip the googling and just use a dictionary. Here you go: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-er. It will immediately tell you both the term you can then search for (agent noun suffix) *and* that the exact same suffix is used in German (little wonder, both English and German being Germanic languages). The only difference being that German still uses umlauts and the infinitive ending *-en*, both of which English no longer does. So rather than tacking on the *-er*, you replace the *-en* with it, and umlaut the root where appropriate. Thus, *zerschlagen → Zerschläger*.

Comment: And that is *all* you need to know. The answer below is needlessly complicated, beating around the bush and raising two new questions for every question it tries to address.

Comment: @RegDwight The answer is "complicated" because OP's question wasn't "How can I create a random noun with the stem of a verb?".

Comment: @RegDwight If you have any knowledge on when umlauts are "appropriate", I invite you to improve both this site and the answer below.

Comment: @Grantwalzer "appropriate" is obviously weasel wording, and it's weasel wording for a reason. There is no rule that can cover all cases. It is random. You cannot explain away why it's Sänger but not Spränger. It is completely impossible. Existing words you just have to learn by heart. And new words are coined by analogy with existing words. If you can find no analogy, then it's a free for all. I would very much like to improve the answer below, but that would involve deleting nine tenths of it, and I imagine that wouldn't sit well with you.

Comment: @RegDwight I was never looking for one rule covering all cases, I was and am looking for a set of guidelines that will cover most of the cases. Because that's what makes a good answer to this question. You can't just let OP go around forming words like Zerschlager or the like. If your answer is that contrary, then I would suggest that you add one yourself.

Comment: @RegDwight Aside from that, your analogy with *Spränger* is an invalid one. There may be exceptions and cases where you really can't tell, but umlauts are certainly not random - patterns in language do actually exist.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: *springen–sprang–gesprungen-spränge → Springer*; *singen–sang–gesungen-sänge → Sänger*. If that is not a valid analogy, then "valid" has no meaning. Also, I never said patterns didn't exist. I said they were random. And anyway: any pattern, by definition, is descriptive rather than prescriptive. Just because X and Y behave the same, doesn't mean Z will. Lastly, *Zerschlager* is very much a valid option; the only reason we prefer *Zerschläger* is by analogy to *schlagen→Schläger* (which is a very weak analogy to boot, as *schlagen→Schlager* exists as well).

Comment: @RegDwight You are abusing two things: 1) The fact that *Sänger* replaced *Singer*, wich perfectly fits the pattern. 2) The conjunctive II.

Comment: The reason *Zerschlager* is not an option here, is because *Schlager* already has meaning that is not compatible with the prefix *zer-*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are talking about [agent nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun).

`VERB STEM+er` does that for many German verbs, technically. But it does not always make sense or sound natural:

> läuten → Läuter?
>   regnen → Regner?
>   zerschlagen → Zerschläger? or Zerschlager? (some people will refuse the second version because "Schlager" already exists as word for "popular song")

Sometimes, it describes (predominantly) something for doing something:

> bohren → Bohrer (drill)
>   schlagen → Schläger (bat, racket, stick)
>   mixen → Mixer (kitchen mixer, less frequently used in context with beverages or music)

Furthermore, the transformation does not always describe someone who `VERBs`:

> schauen → Schauer (to look and shower)
>   füllen → Füller (to fill and filler/pen)
>   bauen → Bauer (to build and peasant)
>   lenken → Lenker (to steer or drive and handlebar; "Lenker" actually does have "driver" as second meaning, but mainly in Austria and Switzerland)

---

Here are some guidelines the community has come up with so far:

**General**

- Despite the two counterexamples above, the verb to be transformed should actually describe some acting.
  bleiben, meinen → Bleiber?, Meiner?
- If the verb ends on `-eln` the Suffix is `-ler`.
  sammeln, basteln, wickeln → Sammler, Bastler, Wickler
- Pay attention on verbs ending on '-rn'. Their stem is everything but the 'n'. zaubern → Zauberer
- For a female agens, `-in` is appended.
  Bastler, Mörder, Werfer → Bastlerin, Mörderin, Werferin

**Umlauts**

- *A* in the stem often becomes *ä* if the verb has strong inflection.
  tragen, backen, verraten → Träger, Bäcker, Verräter
  but: beraten → Berater (even though beraten is conjugated the same way as verraten)
  On the other hand, sometimes also weak verbs change *a* to *ä*.
  jagen → Jäger
- In its present form, this "rule" cannot be applied to *au*.
  tauchen (weak), rauben (weak) → Taucher, Räuber
  <sup>Although *Räuber* could be an exception like *Sänger*.</sup>
- One example for *o* becoming *ö* was found, yet its inflection is weak.
  morden → Mörder
- *U* seems not to change, even with strong verbs: rufen → Rufer

**Exceptions**

Note that singer was normal German, too (and [Meistersinger](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meistersinger) is still known to contemporary speakers thanks to the popular opera by Wagner). It was replaced by *Sänger*. So *singen* does not actually become *Sänger*, it's just that the two words are so old, they've undergone different developements.

---

Another similar but not equal possibility is to use the first participle of the verb as a noun:

> zerschlagen → der Zerschlagende

Although you dismissed this possibility, I think there are some cases where it works as you want it to:

> der Wissende (one who knows)
>   der Suchende (one who searches)

Comment: a becoming ä is only true for verbs with strong inflection: Bäcker, Träger, Schläger ... If the verb is weak, however, the a does not change: Raser, Maler, Mahner, Bastler, etc.

Comment: Also, au does not always become äu: Taucher, Brauer, Erbauer, [Hauer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hauer). And I think it's worth mentioning that nouns constructed this way may also describe tools or other things involved in the action: Bohrer, Schaber, Schläger, Sucher (in a camera). And sometimes they can even have a different meaning that is more or less unrelated: Bürger (in contrast to Bürge!), Bauer, [Füller](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fueller), Schauer.

Comment: There is also (at least) one transformation from o to ö: morden → Mörder.

Comment: @Ingmar No rule without exceptions: `jagen` has weak inflection, yet the noun is `Jäger`. On the other hand `beraten` has strong inflection, but the noun is `Berater`. And `verraten` is conjugated the same way, but here `Verräter` follows the rule.

Comment: @Matthias I've made the post community wiki, so if you're up for it, you can edit in your (great) findigs.

Comment: While Bleiber sounds weird indeed, I think combinations like Sitzenbleiber (pupil who repeats a class) are common.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Enough context provided, even *Bleiber* can mean something.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Took some time, but now my 2 cents are in. As you can see, I slightly disagree on "Zerschläger". It sounds strange anyway, but I'd rather say "der Zerschlager des Persischen Reichs". Don't know why, it's just my personal *Sprachgefühl*.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you for the verbs on *-rn*, completetly missed that.

Answer (score -2):

In theory you can put the ending -er to any verb, but this ending has a special meaning. If you derive a agent noun X-er from a verb X, a X-er is not just someone or something that is doing X, but whose innate character is doing x. For example, Lehrer (from lehren - to teach) is not just someone who is teaching, but someone whose profession is teaching. Bohrer is not just a thing that drills, but a thing whose sole purpose is to drill. So the ending -er is often used for professions (if persons) and tools (if things). Lehrer refers only to a person whose profession is teaching, Schläger refers to a person who regulary beats others up, Mixer is something designed to mix. It has no other intendet function. Examples like Mörder - murderer might look like they contradict this, cause a murderer might only murder for once, but he will always be a murderer, so in this case -er is nevertheless correct.
Zerschläger does not exist in german, cause there is no such thing like a Zerschläger, but if you invent something with the appropriate function, you could call it Zerschläger. Though there is the similar word Zerstörer wich denotes a special type of warships and someone or something that destroys (just like the word destroyer).

Comment: That's rubbish. There agent nouns do not have any such aspect included. The examples you mention are nouns homonymous to agent nouns - 'Zerstörer' can be an agent noun for anybody that destroys or has destroyed once, but there is a class of warships with the same name. The semantics are generally no different from English, e.g., perpretator.

Comment: @shuhalo I think the problem here is your assumption, that `Xer` describes someone who *is doing* something.