# Gibt es Regeln, ob die Fremdadjektivierung durch das Suffix "-orisch" oder "-iv" gebildet wird?

Tags: adjective, loanword, suffix, word-formation

Manche Fremdwörter enden in ihrer Adjektivableitung mit dem Suffix "-orisch" oder "-iv". In vielen Fällen gibt es jeweils nur eine richtige Variante, aber es gibt auch Beispiele, in denen beides, z.T. auch mit einer dann anderen Bedeutung, möglich ist:

> legislatorisch - legislativ
>   argumentatorisch - argumentativ
>   reflektorisch - reflexiv
>   provokatorisch - provokativ
>   ...

Meine Recherchen haben ergeben, dass die [Suffigierung "-orisch"](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe-F/orisch.html?MenuId=WordFormationRules111629) nur bei einer **Nomenableitung** eines Fremdwortes mit der Endung "-ion" vorkommt *(Argumentation, Provokation, Reflexion, ...)* und die [Suffigierung "-iv"](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe-F/iv.html?lang=de) sowohl bei einer **Verb** zu Adjektiv als auch bei **Nomen** zu Adjektiv Ableitung vorkommt. Dies hilft mir aber wenig, wenn ich die richtige Endung finden will, und es erschließt sich mir auch nicht an den obigen Beispielen.

Frei erfundende Adjektivableitungen klingen zwar gefühlsmäßig richtig, aber es gibt sie nicht (z.B. *aggressorisch, expressorisch, subversorisch, ..., kompensativ, illusiv, halluzinativ, ...*). Warum?

Gibt es eine Regel zur Adjektivableitung, oder muss ich das jeweils lernen, bzw. nachschlagen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**-or**

Rein technisch kann an lateinische PPP-Stämme* *-or* angehängt werden. Fast immer bezeichnet man damit jemanden oder etwas, der oder das die im Stamm ausgedrückte Handlung betreibt.

Beispiele:

```
Infinitiv Präsens | PPP        | -or       | Bedeutung
------------------+------------+-----------+------------------------
vincere           | victus     | victor    | Sieger, der Siegreiche
movere            | motus      | motor     | Beweger, Fortrücker
cantare           | cantus     | cantor    | Kirchensänger
narrare           | narratus   | narrator  | Erzähler (Englisch)
aggredi           | aggressus  | aggressor | Angreifer, Angeher
imperare          | imperatus  | imperator | Herrscher, Kaiser
```

„Rein technisch“, weil viele Formen wahrscheinlich erst später gebildet wurden und/oder nur in bestimmten Sprachen überlebt haben. Außerdem haben manche Bildungen eine abweichende Bedeutung, [so wie auch im Deutschen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/is-there-a-way-to-form-a-one-who-verbs-noun/).

Die Formen auf *or-* zu den Beispielen aus der Frage:

> Legislator *([nur im Englischen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legislator),   viele würden es wegen Legislatur → Gesetzgebung → Gesetzgeber auch so verstehen)*
>   Argumentator *([nur im Englischen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/argumentator), [oder?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=argumentator&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CArgumentator%3B%2Cc0))*
>   Reflektor (erst später, Bedeutungswandlung)
>   Provokateur (eingedeutscht französisch für *provocator*!)

**-orisch**

Wiederum rein technisch kann man im Deutschen an fast jedes (türisch?) Substantiv die ganz unaufregende Endung *-isch* anhängen, um daraus ein Adjektiv im Sinne von *X betreffend / in der Art von X* zu machen. Und meiner Meinung nach ist damit das „Fremdsuffix“ *-orisch* geboren. Auch hier gibt es wieder Ausnahmen, das Schema hält dennoch weitgehend:

> legislatorisch → gesetzgeberisch
>   argumentatorisch → das Argumentierte betreffend, in der Art eines Argumentierenden
>   reflektorisch → *(heute)* durch einen Reflex bedingt, *(nach Schema)* das Abwendende betreffend?
>   provokatorisch → in der Art eines Provozierenden, den Provokateur betreffend

Diese zwei (sprachlich) natürlichen Schemata sind auch der Grund dafür, dass sich „erfundene“ Ableitungen natürlich anhören. Das ist ja das Geniale an der Sprache: Auch neugeformte Wörter werden verstanden, wenn sie eine bekannte Bauweise aufweisen. Wie wenn man behaupten würde, Laptophaufen sei kein Wort. Hier ein gesundes Junges:

> aggressorisch → in der Art eines Aggressors (z. B. manche Staaten)

**-iv**

Diese Endung entstammt der Lateinischen Adjektivendung *-ivus/-iva/-ivum*:

```
agere     | actus     | activus     (-or auch möglich!)
aggredi   | aggressus | aggressivus (nachgebildet)
possedere | possessus | possesivus  (possessor!)
```

Sie verwandelt also das dem Verbstamm innewohnende direkt in ein Adjektiv, während *-orisch* den Stamm zuerst in einen „Täter“ verwandelt, und dann ein Adjektiv daraus formt. (Vorsicht, *-iv* kann auch Substantivstämme in Adjektive umwandeln.)

**Zusammenfassend**

Wörter gleichen Stammes durchmachen aber nicht notwendigerweise dieselbe Bedeutungswandlung, was dazu führt, dass man bei einem Akteur nicht primär an die Eigenschaft „aktiv“ denkt. Auf der anderen Hand geben die Pärchen *argumentativ* und *argumentatorisch*, sowie *possessiv* und *possessorisch* weniger Spielraum her, da spezifischer als bloßes *handeln*. Man könnte eventuell meinen, dass die Adjektivvariante auf *-iv* den Aspekt des Handelns/Gehandelten nicht in dem Maße unterstreicht, wie es *-orisch* tut (man bedenke nur, dass die PPP-Stämme Stämme von *Tunwörtern* sind.)

Man könnte also 1) sagen, dass sich die Adjektive auf *-iv* und *-orisch* desto ähnlicher sind, je weniger Bedeutungswandlung stattgefunden hat oder (bei Neubildungen) möglich ist.

Sollte 2) darauf achten, dass man *-orisch* nicht an einen vermeintlichen PPP-Stamm anhängt. (massatorisch?)

Muss 3) bedenken, dass *-iv* Adjektive verschiedener Art bilden kann (lukrativ), während *-orisch* an einen „Täter“ gebunden ist. (lukratorisch?)

Et 4), nulla regula sine exceptione, nam nonnullae conformationes simpliciter absurdae sunt: kantorisch? But who knows...

---

<sup>Anmerkung: Endung *-or* im Lateinischen so wie im Deutschen *-er*!; nicht zu verwechseln mit der 1. Person Singular Präsens Passiv Indikativ, die oft auf -or endet.</sup>